# Laravel map only works on first loop

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a collection that works with array map. However, it only works if I have only one object in the collection.

My function:

```
$vacancies->map(function ($vacancie) {
            $vacancie['url'] = url(route('frontendShowVacancies', ['companyTitle' => urlencode($vacancie->company->title), 'vacancie' => $vacancie->id]));
            $vacancie['company']['images'][0]['url'] = url(route('companyImage', ['uuid' => $vacancie['company']['images'][0]['uuid']]));
            $vacancie['company']['image'] = $vacancie['company']['images'][0];
            $vacancie['company']['images'] = '';
            $vacancie['startDate'] = Carbon::parse($vacancie['startDate'])->format('d.m.Y');
            $vacancie['endDate'] = Carbon::parse($vacancie['endDate'])->format('d.m.Y');
            return $vacancie;
        });
```

I am getting:

```
Uninitialized string offset: 0
```

It refers t the 2nd line inside the function (`$vacancie['company']['images'][0]['url']...`). I know that `$vacancie['company']['images']` is an array with 0 is filled. What is going on? why am I getting the error?

Comment: seems you've overwritten it on this line `$vacancie['company']['images'] = '';` as you know `map()` loops through the data.

Comment: I know. But why does it gives the error? I want to set $vacancie[company][images] property for every item in the collection on empty. I don’t unterstand why gives the error.

Comment: Could you `dd($vacancie)` inside your callback and add it to your question?

Comment: Also, maybe a `dd($vacancies)` -- Just want to make sure all your records have an image set.

Comment: I dont know exactly why, but as @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin suggested, if I remove the line, it works. Thanks! But I would like to exclude the `$vacancie['company']['images']` array from the result. How is this done?

Comment: If you exclude it then you can's set it here `$vacancie['company']['images'][0]['url'] = url(route(...` You can either build a new array in the `map()` block then fill in your desired values.